# Getting Numerical Frequency Table for a Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, frequency-distribution

i would like to know, how can i do the following. My input table is as follows

| Sr No | Data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John Apple Android |
| 2 | John Apple Microsoft Ryan |
| 3 | Sam Android Microsoft Ryan Paul |

i broke the data column into individual dataframes using the str.split() method and from list to dataframe. I have also created a structure based on the classification I had on Names from another table. So all the names are to be columns. i already know the list of names that i need which would be my final column names. The data is to be read as follows

row 1 - John owns an Apple and an Android device

output after row 1

|  | John | Ryan | Sam | Paul |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Android | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Microsoft | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

row 2 - John owns Apple (now the count for that becomes 2) and Microsoft.
Ryan owns Apple and Microsoft (count for Ryan on Microsoft row becomes 1)

Output after Row 2

|  | John | Ryan | Sam | Paul |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Android | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Microsoft | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

row 3 - Ryan owns Android (count = 1) and Microsoft (count for Ryan on Microsoft row becomes 2).
Sam owns Android (count = 1) and Microsoft (count on Microsoft row becomes 1).
Paul owns Android (count = 1) and Microsoft (count on Microsoft row becomes 1).

Output after Row 3

|  | John | Ryan | Sam | Paul |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Android | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Microsoft | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |

i have over 2mn records which have the column values similar as the one in the Data column and need to create a similar distribution table with over 200 names and 400+ device categories.(simplified the categories)

Comment: Please share the code you have written while attempting this task.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. `extractall` the names from each row
2. Get all the devices from each row by replacing the names
3. `merge` the data to map each name with the corresponding device
4. `crosstab` to get the frequency table

```
columns = ["John", "Ryan", "Sam", "Paul"]

names = df["Data"].str.extractall(f'({"|".join(columns)})').droplevel(1).squeeze().rename("Name")
devices = df["Data"].str.replace(f'({"|".join(columns)})',"",regex=True).str.strip().str.split(" ").rename("Device")

data = names.to_frame().merge(devices, left_index=True, right_index=True)
data = data.explode("Device")

output = pd.crosstab(data["Device"], data["Name"]).rename_axis(None, axis=1).rename_axis(None)

>>> output
           John  Paul  Ryan  Sam
Android       1     1     1    1
Apple         2     0     1    0
Microsoft     1     1     2    1
```

Comment: Got the following error when attempting for 2mn rows. and i have about 16 Gigs of RAM


MemoryError: Unable to allocate 13.5 GiB for an array with shape (1813361280,) and data type object

Comment: can this be broken down at a function level?